# Is it possible to use P4Python API with IronPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, perforce, p4python

Is it possible to use P4Python (the perforce python api) with IronPython? I'd like to use the python api because it seems much faster than using p4.net implementionat of a Perforce API but when I try to import p4 into IronPython I receive the following error.

> IronPython 2.6.1 (2.6.10920.0) on .NET
>   4.0.30128.1 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
>   information.
>
> > > > import P4 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1,
> > > >         in    File "C:\Program
> > > >         Files\IronPython 2.6 for .NET
> > > >         4.0\lib\site-packages\P4.py", l ine 210, in  ImportError: No
> > > >         module named P4API

Comment: I'm surprised that p4.net is slower than using p4python as p4.net wraps the native perforce c/c++ api. There will be a bit of an overhead due to marshalling etc but it shouldn't be significant.
What are the specific bottlenecks you're finding?

Comment: I must have been misusing p4.net, because I went back and revisited the api and reimplemented in a new project and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess P4API is CPython extension so it does not work in IronPython. In that case, try [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/).

Comment: I tried using Ironclad and it enables me to import the P4 Python API but basic functionality is not working. Thanks for the suggestion of Ironclad.